# Linux user not being able to login (/bin/nologin)

Tags: users, login

I work on a shared linux enviroment (CentOS), but for some reason one of my logins has been locked. When I do a `cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home"`, I can find my user:

```
roaming:x:579:579::/home/roaming:/bin/nologin
```

I've got root permission, but don't know what to do to be able to login again.

What should I do about this '`no login`' thing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man 8 nologin` There is your real answer as to why it isn't working.

If you want the user to log in then you need to give them a shell like `/bin/bash` or something else.

You can edit `/etc/passwd` directly or use `usermod -s /bin/bash roaming`, all of this needs to be done as root.

Comment: I'm really new to linux, so please don't kill me for my noob question: While in the root, I've tried the command but the output was:

[root@nagioserver01 ~]# usermod roaming -s /bin/bash
usermod : user /bin/bash does not exist

Comment: @ZeldaElf Sorry about that, I had the order mixed. Put the username last, the post has been updated.

Comment: Just to understand: What did you mean by "giving them a shell"?

Comment: Well, a user needs some sort of shell to interact with the system, from a webserver program to the person sitting in a chair they all need a shell. `nologin` is used when an account is disabled or when they shouldn't have a shell that they can interact with.

Comment: @ZeldaElf by the way, if you are happy with the answer I've provided, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, fella! I could not accept it before because you answered it less than 5 minutes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you have root, try

```
chsh --shell /bin/bash raoming
```

where

- chsh : change shell
- --shell /bin/bash tel to use /bin/bash
- roaming : your user.